# Read a QName from an XML using Java / DOM

Tags: java, xml

I have a QName encoded in an XML file as below. How do I read it in to a Java javax.xml.namespace.QName? Also is this a proper way to encode a QName in an XML

```
<messages>
    <message>
        <qname xmlns:msg-i="http://www.abc.com/message">msg-i:InformationMessage</qname>
    </message>
</messages>
```

and Java code

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document messagesDoc = db.parse(file);
messagesDoc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList messages = messagesDoc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("message");

for (int i = 0; i < messages.getLength(); i++) {
    //read the QName here
    QName qname = ...;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's better way to parse the xml elements and it's tag values, use Node and Element interface to  iterate between the child nodes to parse the  xml element values .I hop it would help you ..